# can't get a delete command working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

can someone explain what is wrong with this delete command, i am trying to delete a row from my table which contains some information about a flight and then replace it with a new one. The insertion works fine but the deletion won't work. any help would be great thanks

```
        OleDbCommand deleteCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        sqlStr = "DELETE FROM tblFlights WHERE Arrivals = '" + arrival + "'";

        connection.Open();
        // delete setup
        deleteCmd.Connection = connection;
        deleteCmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
        //activate the deletion
        dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = deleteCmd;
```

More info can be given if needed

Comment: More info is needed. What's the error message? Table definition? The value of the `arrival` variable? Have you tried running this SQL statement directly, rather than by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not actually run the command. You're missing this:

```
deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, you might want to look out for SQL Injection.

Comment: Thank you muchly this has been annoying me for literally 2 hours  lol

Comment: i will investigate into SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this as it's prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I know it is, this is just a very basic version so far, it isn't going to be for commercial use  :)

Comment: Ok ... then yes, as they said, ExecuteNonQuery() is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as suggested above, you need to:

```
deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

for the command to actually be executed.

is Arrivals a string? if so then try and trim both values when it compares:

```
sqlStr = "DELETE FROM tblFlights WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Arrivals)) = LTRIM(RTRIM('" + arrival + "'))";
```

If that does not work then do the below select and see what it returns:

```
SELECT * FROM tblFlights WHERE Arrivals = 'Your Arrival'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is succeptable to SQL Injection attacks, take a look at my own question for ways to prevent such attacks and use secure queries - [Method Optimisation - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518857/method-optimisation-c)